# Start Mule Flows Stopped/toggling flows

Tags: mule, mule-studio

So I have an application with multiple flows, for multiple clients. What I'm looking to do is have a way to toggle this flows on and off at the needs of each client.

I setup a flow to monitor a folder for a file that I basically call muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct(flow).start/stop depending on each line of the file. This part works great, and does what I'd expect.

Now the tricky part I'm struggling to figure out, is every time I deploy the application, all flows run once before my flow reads the properties file and disables the flows that need to be disabled. Is there a way to have flows default off, so we can easily toggle them without having to redeploy the whole app with them excluded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set flow initial state to stopped:

```
<flow name="main" initialState="stopped">
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I've spent the last couple days trying to figure out a way to do that. Is this in the documentation somewhere that I missed?